# IF AND Formula in VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Recently you guys helped me solve looping through a pivot table by inserting a dynamic formula next to a pivot table and auto filling down.

```
'formula
 frml = "=if(" & myrange.Address(0, 0) & ">0.3%," & myrange2.Address(0, 0) & ","""")"

'where i want the formula to go
pt.ColumnRange.End(xlToRight).Offset(1, 0).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 1).formula = frml

ActiveSheet.range("P7:P36588").FillDown
```

I've tried updating this formula by adding

```
"=if(and("
```

and then also adding in another range. Problem is the additional `(` never shows up. I've also tried just adding `"("` as it's own part but then the next part (the 'where the formula goes) stops working which makes no sense to me.

Can someone help me convert this formula into an ifand statement and also explain why the 'where the formula should go' part all of the sudden stops working?

---

**Edit**:

In total, the new addition would look like this:

```
"if(and(" & myrange.address(0,0) & ">0.3%," & myrange3.address(0,0) & ">$100," & myrange2.address(0,0) & ","""")
```

to output this formula in the corresponding cell by the pivot table

```
=if(and(c3>.3%,d3>$100),a3,""
```

the problem right now is adding that `and` part to the formula which would be d3. If those 2 statements work, then it should bring out a3, if not it will return nothing.

Comment: You need to post the new addition to your formula so we can see what went wrong, and also what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @ShaiRado hey! Thanks for replying. I just updated my initial question. Hope that helps. To give more context, here is a link to my previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442648/create-if-then-formula-with-ranges-as-values?noredirect=1#comment85907322_49442648

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of notes:

1. @Jeeped already answered the reason to your error - you need to add closing bracket `)` to your `AND`.
2. I like to use `Chr(34)` to write down `"` inside formula strings.
3. I like to avoid comparing the formats inside the cell, just the values. So instead of `myrange.address(0,0) & ">0.3%"` I like using `myrange.address(0,0) & ">0.003"`.

**Code**

```
frml = "=IF(AND(" & myrange.Address(0, 0) & ">0.003," & myrange3.Address(0, 0) & ">100)," & myrange2.Address(0, 0) & "," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Comment: This works, I gave you the check for your thorough explanation! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You aren't closing off the AND clause with a `)`.

```
'formula
frml = "=if(and(" & myrange.address(0,0) & ">0.3%, " & myrange3.address(0,0) & ">$100), " & myrange2.address(0,0) & ", text(,))
```

`text(,)` is a good substitute for `""""` in a quoted string formula.